# Wolfram Cloud: How to set language of a notebook

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I am located in Germany so I usually use the German language. In Mathematica I alway write and publish in the English language, so all my Mathematica feels are in English and the language in Mathematica is set to English. Now I put a few files in the Wolfram cloud to work with them, when traveling on my iPad, or via a browser. Here the language is German and I get most words underlined (marked as typo) because they are in English. Up to now I cloud not figure out how to switch the language her.
Maybe it is simple and I have overseen the obvious, but... any hint is welcome....

Answer (score 2):

Just click on your user icon "Account and Settings" in the upper right corner, select Preferences and uncheck "Check spelling as you type". This will stop the red underlining.

[image]

Or, alternatively, just set the language like this:
[image]